# Short Lines Either Side Text

Tags: html, css

Using CSS and HTML there are a load of answers for adding a line either side of some text but these lines always fill the full width of the container. I only want these lines to be 150px in length either side of the text like this:

[image: example of what the lines should look like]

The text will be dynamic so may change in length and needs to be centred.

Here is some jsfiddle code I have been working on:

https://jsfiddle.net/vh0j4q1e/

```
<div id="container">
```

## TEXT HEADING

```
#container {
width:800px;
text-align:center;
background-color:#ccc;
}
h1 {
position: relative;
font-size: 30px;
z-index: 1;
overflow: hidden;
text-align: center;
}
h1:before, h1:after {
position: absolute;
top: 51%;
overflow: hidden;
width: 50%;
height: 3px;
content: '';
background-color: red;
}
h1:before {
margin-left: -50%;
text-align: right;
}
```

Can anyone help improve this code so the lines appear as per the image above?

Comment: Wrap the container in div in fixed the width.

Answer (score 10):

You could use `Flexbox` here

```css
h2 {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

h2:after, h2:before {
  content: '';
  width: 150px;
  height: 2px;
  background: red;
  margin: 0 10px;
}
```

```html
<h2>Lorem ipsum</h2>
```

Answer (score 3):

And if you don't want to use `Flexbox`, you could do it by making `h1` an `inline-block` then offsetting the `:before` -150px to the left and `:after` to 100% left

```css
#container {
  width:800px;
  text-align:center;
  background-color:#ccc;
  margin:0 auto;
}

h1 {
    position: relative;
    font-size: 30px;
    display: inline-block;
    padding:0 15px;
}

h1:before, h1:after {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    width: 150px;
    height: 3px;
    content: '';
    background-color: red;
    left:-150px;
}

h1:after {
  left: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <h1>TEXT HEADING</h1>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/azizn/vh0j4q1e/1/

Answer (score 3):

Here's another approach.  I haven't tested it very much, but it should be pretty cross-browser

```css
#container {
  width:800px;
  max-width: 100%;
  text-align:center;
  background-color:#ccc;
}
h1 {
    position: relative;
    font-size: 30px;
    z-index: 1;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: center;
}
h1:before, h1:after {
    content: '';
    width: 150px;
    height: 3px;
    display:inline-block;
    background-color: red;
    vertical-align: 0.3em;
    margin: 0 -100%;
}
h1:before {
  margin-right: 0.75em;
}
h1:after {
  margin-left: 0.75em;
}
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <h1>TEXT HEADING</h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here, I've both wrapped it in another DIV for centering AND gave the title a little more space (a la the example):

https://jsfiddle.net/vh0j4q1e/

```
<div align="center">
  <div id="container">
    <h1>TEXT HEADING</h1>
  </div>
</div>

#container {
  width:800px;
  text-align:center;
  background-color:#ccc;
}
h1 {
    position: relative;
    font-size: 30px;
    z-index: 1;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: center;
}
h1:before, h1:after {
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 15px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 51%;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 50%;
    height: 3px;
    content: '';
    background-color: red;
}
h1:before {
    margin-left: -52%;
    text-align: right;
}
```